# Разделить исходный файл по n-му количеству строк(аналог команды split в Linux) - C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с проблемой. Не получается разделить файл.

```
void splitFile(string path)
{
    int s = 0;
    char S[256];
    int k = 10;
    string q[6] = {"a","b","c","d","e","f"};
    int i = 0;
        ifstream in(path);

        while (!in.eof())
        {
            fstream fout("xa" + q[i]);
            fout.seekg(0, ios_base::end);
            in.getline(S, 256);

            fout << S << "\n";
            if (s = k)
            {
                s = 0;
                i++;
            }
            s++;
            fout.close();
        }

        in.close();
}
```

Подскажите, как реализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум заменить

```
if (s = k)
```

на

```
if (s == k)
```

И еще - проверка `while (!in.eof())` вас огорчит, потому что она сработает только **после** неудачного чтения, так что последнее чтение `in.getline(S,256);` будет неудачным, и вы начнете спрашивать, почему у вас две одинаковые строки в конце...